# Howto fix TableView right margin? (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, tableview

I've created a tableview within Viewcontroller and inserted *disclosure indicator*, but it is not showing, because the right margin is not correct.

What I tried:
selecting table and click in xCode on "pin" button and set left and right to 0, select there *all frames in container* and clicked: *add constraints*

but without results.

How can i fix this?
I attached the problem as image. (i have added a frame to focus the problem)

[image: right margin]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem was not the margin/layout.

To show *disclosure indicator* in tableview cell's, it is needed to select *disclosure indicator* from *Accessory* menu AND give a *identifier* for the cell.
Without given *identifier* the *disclosure indicator* is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, there can be multiple reasons for which this can happen. For instance, one can forget to deck the cell with wrong identifier or may have set the accessory Indicator in a wrong way. My personal assumption is you probably have set constrain improperly.

So, I am just going to show you the whole process.

Step 1: Drag and UITableView inside your ViewController and drag a UITableViewCell inside that TableView. Select the Table View Cell and assign an identifier. Make sure, in your datasource method, -cellForRowAtIndexPath, you use this same identifier.

[image]

Step 2: Go to your View Controller and take an IBOutlet of a UITableView.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>

      @property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;

@end
```

Step 3: Go to the connection Inspector of your storyboard and connect the UITableView with this outlet.

Step 4: Go to the implementation file of your View Controller and populate the datasource methods. Also make sure, you set your TableView's datasource to your view controller.

[image]

Now when you build and run this code you won't see the accessory Indicator.

[image]

The reason is you didn't set the constraints.

Step 4: Just set the constrains like the following and you are good to go.

[image]

This is my final view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change seperator inset inorder to remove left margin. Its set to default change it to **custom** and make left insets and right insets to **zero**. You can set the **'Separator Inset'** from the storyboard:

[image]

**Change Seperator insets to Custom and make left to zero**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try to programmatically set the width and height of the tableView like so...

```
@IBOutlet weak var resultsTable: UITableView! // connect to tableView

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
  let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

  resultsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, theWidth, theHeight)
}
```

Comment: also nothing is changed